# PHP Cutting the last few characters of a filename

Tags: php

I am retrieving file locations and names from a database, the are in this format

http://domain.com/subdir/etc/etc/etc/picimage-niceone_Main-150x150.jpg

They are all dynamic, so there are hundreds of them all with different names, but one thing is constant is the last - and then the file dimensions.

What i need to do is strip everything after the last - so it turns into the following.

http://domain.com/subdir/etc/etc/etc/picimage-niceone_Main.jpg

Any help would be awesome.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stringName = "picimage-niceone_Main-150x150.jpg";
$newName = substr($stringName,0,strrpos($stringName,"-")).substr($stringName,-4);
```

This will remove anything between the last `-` and the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `preg_replace()`:

```
$url = preg_replace('/\-(\d+)x(\d+)(\.\w+)$/', '$3', $url);
```

i.e. find a hyphen, a number, an 'x', a number, and an extension, and replace the whole thing with just the extension.

Alternatively, if you actually want to know what those width and height values were (for example to populate `<IMG>` tag attributes:

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/subdir/etc/etc/etc/picimage-niceone_Main-150x150.jpg';
$regex = '/(.*?)-(\d+)x(\d+)(\.\w+)$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)) {
  $width = $matches[2];
  $height = $matches[3];
  $url = $matches[1] . $matches[4];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newname = preg_replace("/-[^-.]*(\\.[a-zA-Z]*)$/", '$1', $oldname);
```